Bounding a number-theoretic integral

Find a good upper bound on $$\int_1^T\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)\zeta(1-s)}X^sdt,$$ where $s=c+it$ for a constant $c>1$ and $X>0$ is a parameter. If needed, we can assume RH.

My attempt here is to use the functional equation of $\zeta$, namely $\zeta(s)=\chi(s)\zeta(1-s)$ for a specific function $\chi$. Using this, we see $\chi(s)=\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(1-s)}$. This converts our integral to $$\int_1^{T}\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}\chi(s)X^sdt.$$ Further, we know asymptotically (due to Stirling) that for large $t$, $$\chi(c+it)\sim (t/2\pi)^{1/2-c-it}e^{it+i\pi/4},$$ so my next step was to use the bound $$\left|\frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}(c+iT)\right|=O(\log^2T)$$ together with $|X^s|=X^c$ and the asymptotic for $\chi$. However this fails; the asymptotic works for large $t$ yet our integral runs from $1$ up to $T$, so this approach doesn't work. Is there another way to do this?

What is $X$ here?

@Haidara $X$ is just a parameter, which is at most $T$. I'll add this to the post

Your second integral is not equal to the first one.

The zeta in the denominator must be squared.

@Haidara correct. I'm interested to see how it works in this case though, as in how one could estimate it in its current form

how does it fail? the important part is large $t$ right? however, you shouldn't use the bound for $\zeta'/\zeta $, because then you will lose $\chi $ cancellation. you should keep that explicit using the series expression, and estimate the integral of $\chi (s)$ by exponential sum lemmas (see e.g. Chapter 4 of Titchmarsh)

@tomos could you explain please? I'm not sure why $t$ large is the main contribution. Can you outline how to bound the integral? I will look at Titchmarsh now, thank you!

sure, added in a vague outline now

The integral looks something like $$\sum _{n=1}^\infty \frac {\Lambda (n)}{n^c}\int _1^Tt^{1/2-c}\cdot e(t-t\log (X/nt))\cdot dt\hspace {10mm}e(z)=e^{2\pi iz}.$$
The derivative of the phase is something like $\log t\gg 1$ and oscillatory integrals are bounded by the derivative (see earlier lemmas of Ch4 of Titchmarsh), so here we'd like to say that the integral is $$\ll T^{1/2-c}$$ which is a big saving on the absolute value bound $\ll T^{3/2}$. The problem is that I spoke too vaguely about the derivative - looking at it more carefully we see that it is $\log (X/nt)$ so there's a problem if this gets close to zero. In that case you have to analyse the integral more precisely around $t=X/n$, a process called the method of stationary phase (see slightly later lemmas of Ch4 of Titchmarsh). You should get something like the square-root of the second derivative, so here $\sqrt t$, giving you a total bound for the integral $\ll T^{1-c}$ which is still $\sqrt T$ better than the absolute value bound.

Thank you! So if I understand correctly we're saying that $\int_1^T\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}\chi(s)X^sdt=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\Lambda(n)(X/n)^c\int_1^T(X/n)^{it}\chi(c+it)dt$? In that case how does the $\ll T^{1/2-c}$ arise? Because in our case $c>1$ which means as $T$ gets large the integral gets small. Could you give some more explanation? I think the main part is to evaluate the integral and then combine with the sum, but I can't see a nice way of doing this because of the $\chi$ factor

assuming $c\in (1,3/2)$ then the integral of $t^{1/2-c}$ gets bigger as $t$ gets bigger

but if we claim that the integral itself is $\ll T^{1/2-c}$ then if $c=1.2$ for example we are saying the integral is $\ll T^{-0.7}$ which decays as $T$ gets large?

if the integrand is something like $1/t^{1/2}$ then  the integral is like $T^{1/2}$

Actually how did you deduce in the first place that $\int_{1}^T{X/n}^{it}\chi(c+it)dt=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-c}\Lambda(n)\int_1^Tt^{1/2-c}e^{i(t-t\log(X/nt))}$? I agree that we should get a von mangoldt type sum, but I'm not sure where the integral comes from. We know $(X/n)^{it}=e^{it\log(X/n)}$ so our integrand should be $e^{it\log(X/n)}\chi(c+it)$ (or maybe the abs value), but the derivative of the phase is zero so stationary phase doesnt apply (at least if my computation is correct)-- could you elaborate on how you got the integral?

"this converts our integral to..." - from there you put the series for $\zeta '/\zeta $, and then you say $\chi \approx t^{1/2-c}$

ah yes this is where I was getting confused -- I'm not sure why $\chi(c+it)\approx t^{1/2-c}$ (I assume you mean absolute value?) but in any case, I think the absolute value of chi is like that for large t but in the regime where t is small I'm not sure why that is true - modulus of chi decays quickly so the small t seems to be where our problem lies

the asymptotic $\chi (s)=t^{1/2-c}e(...)+\mathcal O(t^{1/2-c-1})$ is true for all $t$

By Stirling we have $\chi(c+it)\sim \left(\frac{t}{2\pi}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}-c-it}e^{it+i\frac{\pi}{4}}$ for large $t$, do you have a reference for this being true for all $t$?

it's true for $t>1000$ say. then for $t<1000$ your last statement statement reads "$\chi (s)=O(1)$"
